# Convergence of the row sums in a triangular null array with zero mean

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, limits-and-convergence

Let $(X_{jn})_{1\leq j \leq n}$, $n\in \mathbb N$, be a triangular array of random vectors in $\mathbb R^d$ (the $X_{jn}$ are understood to be independent in $j$ for fixed $n$.). We say that the triangular array is *null* if $X_{jn} \overset{p}{\to} 0$, as $n \to \infty$, uniformly in $j$, i.e.,:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \max_{1\leq j\leq n} P( \, |X_{jn}|> \epsilon \, )=0, \quad (\forall \, \epsilon>0).
\end{equation}
For any random vector $X$ with distribution $\mu$, we introduce an associated compound Poisson random vector $X^{\tilde{}}$ (Note the tilde, please) with characteristic measure $\mu$, i.e.:
\begin{equation}
\log \varphi_{X^{\tilde{}}}(u) = \int_{\mathbb R^d} (e^{iux}-1)\mu (dx), \quad u \in \mathbb R^d.
\end{equation}
For a triangular array $(X_{jn})_{1\leq j \leq n}$, the corresponding compound Poisson vectors $(X_{jn}^{\tilde{}})_{1\leq j \leq n}$ are again assumed to have row-wise independent entries.

By $X_n \overset{d}{\sim} Y_n$ we mean that, if either side converges in distribution along a sub-sequence, then so does the other along the same sequence.

We can show the proposition about compound Poisson approximation: Let $(X_{jn})_{1\leq j \leq n}$, $n\in \mathbb N$, be a null array of random vectors in $\mathbb R^d$.  Fix $h > 0$, and define:
\begin{equation}\label{k1}\tag{K1}
b_{jn}= E(X_{jn}\,;\,|X_{jn}|\leq h).
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}\label{k2}\tag{K2}
\sum_j X_{jn} \overset{d}{\sim} \sum_j \left\{ (X_{jn} - b_{jn})^{\tilde{}} +b_{jn}  \right\}
\end{equation}
(This the Proposition 7.11  from [Foundations of Modern Probability](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-61871-1), Third edition)

**Update**

Allow me to rephrase my question. We say that a Infinite Divisible r. vector has the levy kintchine representations if its characteristic function is given by:
$$\varphi_X(u)= \exp\left\{i u'b + \frac{1}{2}u'au + \int_{\mathbb R^d} \left[e^{iu'x}-1 - i u'x c(x)\right] d\nu(x) \right\} $$
where $c(x)$ is a integrable function. We denote this as $X \sim (b_c, a, \nu)_c$. In the case above, we have that $X^{\tilde{}} \sim (0,0,\mu)_0$.

Now, we can change the truncation function $c(x)$ by other $h(x)$. If $X \sim (b_c, a, \nu)_c$, we have that
$$X \sim (b_h, a, \nu)_h, \quad b_h = b_c + \int_{\mathbb R^d}x [ h(x)- c(x)]d\nu(x)$$

**Question:**

Given a **Null** triangular array $(X_{jn})_{1\leq j \leq n}$ with $X_{jn} \sim \mu_{jn}$. Suppose $E[X_{jn}]=0$ and we also have that:
\begin{equation}\label{I}\tag{I}
\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf{v}(X_{jn})\leq C< \infty,\quad \forall \, n
\end{equation}
where $X_{jn}=(X_{jn_{1}},..., X_{jn_{d}})$ and:
$$\mathbf{v}(X_{jn}):=\hbox{trace} \left(E\left[X_{jn}X_{jn}^{\,\,'}\right]\right)= \sum_{k=1}^d \hbox{var}(X_{jn_{k}})$$
Note that $X_{jn_{k}}$ is unidemsional, $E[X_{jn_{k}}]=0$ and $\hbox{var}(X_{jn_{k}})= E[(X_{jn_{k}})^2]$.

Define $S_n' \sim (0,0,\mu_n)_h$ with $h(x)\equiv 1$ and $$\mu_n := \sum_{j=1}^n \mu_{jn}$$
So, how to show, using (\ref{k1}) and (\ref{k2}), that:
$$S_n := \sum_j X_{jn} \overset{d}{\sim} S_n' $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$Let us rephrase the question a bit. For each natural $n$, let $X_{1,n},\dots,X_{j_n,n}$ be independent zero-mean random vectors in $\R^d$ such that (i) for each real $\ep>0$
\begin{equation*}
    \max_{j\in J_n} P(\|X_{j,n}\|>\ep)\to0 \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$) and (ii)
for some real $C>0$ and all $n$
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{j\in J_n} E\|X_{j,n}\|^2\le C, \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
where $j_n$ is a positive integer, $J_n:=\{1,\dots,j_n\}$, and $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm. Let
\begin{equation*}
    S_n:=\sum_{j\in J_n} X_{j,n}. 
\end{equation*}

For any random vector $Z$ in $\R^d$, let $f_Z$ denote the characteristic function (ch. f.) of $Z$, so that $f_Z(t)=Ee^{it\cdot Z}$ for $t\in\R^d$, where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product.

For each natural $n$, let $Y_{1,n},\dots,Y_{j_n,n}$ be independent random vectors in $\R^d$ such that for all $j\in J_n$ and all $t\in\R^d$
\begin{equation*}
    f_{Y_{j,n}}(t)=\exp(f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1). 
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{equation*}
    T_n:=\sum_{j\in J_n} Y_{j,n}.
\end{equation*}

The problem is then to show that
\begin{equation*}
    \text{$S_n$ converges in distribution iff $T_n$ converges in distribution.} \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}

Here is a proof. Take any $t\in\R^d$. Note that $|e^{iu}-1|\le\min(2,|u|)$ for all real $u$. So, for each real $\ep>0$,
\begin{equation*}
    |f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|\le E|e^{it\cdot X_{j,n}}-1|\,1(\|X_{j,n}\|\le\ep)
    +E|e^{it\cdot X_{j,n}}-1|\,1(\|X_{j,n}\|>\ep)
    \le\|t\|\ep+2P(\|X_{j,n}\|>\ep)
\end{equation*}
and hence, by \eqref{0},
\begin{equation*}
    \limsup_n\max_{j\in J_n}|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|\le\|t\|\ep. 
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
\max_{j\in J_n}|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|\to0\text{ uniformly in $t$ in any bounded set}. \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}

Note also that $|e^{iu}-1-iu|\le u^2/2\le u^2$ for all real $u$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    |f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|=|E(e^{it\cdot X_{j,n}}-1-it\cdot X_{j,n})|\le E(t\cdot X_{j,n})^2
    \le\|t\|^2 E\|X_{j,n}\|^2. 
\end{equation*}
So, by \eqref{10},
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j\in J_n}|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|\le C\|t\|^2. \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}

It follows from \eqref{30} that for all large enough $n$ (depending on $t$) and all $j\in J_n$ the value of $\ln f_{X_{j,n}}(t)$ is defined and
\begin{equation}
    |\ln f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-(f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1)|\le|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|^2. 
\end{equation}
So, by \eqref{40} and \eqref{30},
\begin{equation}
    \Big|\sum_{j\in J_n}\ln f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-\sum_{j\in J_n}(f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1)\Big|
    \le\sum_{j\in J_n}|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|^2 \\ 
    \le\max_{j\in J_n}|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|\,\sum_{j\in J_n}|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|
    \le C\|t\|^2\max_{j\in J_n}|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|\to0. 
    \tag{50}\label{50}
\end{equation}

Thus, in view of \eqref{50} and \eqref{30},

$S_n$ converges in distribution

iff $\prod_{j\in J_n}f_{X_{j,n}}$ converges pointwise to a function continuous at $0$

iff $\sum_{j\in J_n}\ln f_{X_{j,n}}$ converges pointwise to a function continuous at $0$

iff $\sum_{j\in J_n}(f_{X_{j,n}}-1)$ converges pointwise to a function continuous at $0$

iff $T_n$ converges in distribution.

So, we have \eqref{20}. $\quad\Box$

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you say that for any $t$, we have for each $ \varepsilon > 0$:
\begin{equation*}
|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|\le E|e^{it\cdot X_{j,n}}-1|1(|X_{j,n}|\le\varepsilon) +E|e^{it\cdot X_{j,n}}-1|1(|X_{j,n}|>\varepsilon)
\le|t|\varepsilon+2P(|X_{j,n}|>\varepsilon)
\end{equation*}
First, for the case $|X_{j,n}|\leq \varepsilon$, we have $|e^{it\cdot X_{jn}}-1|\leq \min(2, |t||X|_{j,n}) \overset{(*)}{\leq} |t||X|_{j,n}\leq |t|\varepsilon$, but $(*)$ holds if $|t||X|_{j,n}\leq 2$. If we choose $\varepsilon$ so that $|t|\varepsilon \leq 2$, it's ok.

Comment: However, for the second part:
$$|e^{it\cdot X_{jn}}-1|\leq \min(2, |t||X|_{j,n}) \overset{(**)}{\leq} 2$$
for $(**)$ to be true, it must be, necessarily, $|t||X_{j,n}|\geq 2$, under $|t|\varepsilon \leq 2$ (So that $(*)$ is true.) and $|X_{j,n}|> \varepsilon$. Perhaps this gives scope to find a counterexample. I also don't know if I'm making a mistake in my comment. I'll keep thinking to see if I'm talking nonsense.

Comment: I think I can argue as follows: let any $t$ and any $\varepsilon>0$. We always have 
$$|e^{it\cdot X_{jn}}-1|\leq\min(2,|t||X|_{j,n})\leq b,\quad b=2, |t||X|_{j,n}$$
(i) if $|X_{jn}|\leq\varepsilon$, we use $b=|t||X|_{j,n}$ to conclude that $|e^{it\cdot X_{jn}}-1|\leq |t|\varepsilon.\,\,$(ii) if $X_{jn}>\epsilon$, we set $b=2$. That resolved I have another question (I don't have much experience in complex analysis). When you say that (30)​ is used to ensure that the values of $\ln f_{X_{j,n}}​(t)$ are defined, what exactly do you mean? Are yu saying that $\ln f_{X_{j,n}}​(t)$ are close to 1?

Comment: @PSE : Both $(*) $ and $(**)$ are **always** true, just because for any real $a$ and $b$ we have $\min(a,b)\le a$ and $\min(a,b)\le b$. Alternatively, we can write the inequality $|e^{iu}-1|\le\min(2,|u|)$ as the conjunction of the inequalities $|e^{iu}-1|\le|u|$ and $|e^{iu}-1|\le2$ and then use the first one of the latter two inequalities with $1(\|X_{j,n}\|\le\ep)$ and the second one of those two inequalities with $1(\|X_{j,n}\|>\ep)$. Are any other details needed?

Comment: Dear Iosif, yes, I already understood my mistake. Thanks for the answer. I studied his answer and found it very beautiful. I'll accept your answer, but I'd like to ask one last question: why $|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|=|E(e^{it\cdot X_{j,n}} -1-it\cdot X_{j,n})|$ ? For me, $|f_{X_{j,n}}(t)-1|= |\int e^{it\cdot x} d\nu_{X_{j,n}}(x) -1|= |\int [e^{it\cdot x} - 1 ]d \nu_{X_{j,n}}(x)|=|E(e^{i t\cdot X}-1)|$

Comment: @PSE : This follows because for any random vector $Z$ with $EZ=0$ we have $f_Z(t)-1=Ee^{it\cdot Z}-1=Ee^{it\cdot Z}-1-it\cdot EZ=Ee^{it\cdot Z}-1-E(it\cdot Z)=E(e^{it\cdot Z}-1-it\cdot Z)$. 
Thank you for your appreciation and acceptance of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I just copy some facts(cf.  B. V. Gnedenko & A. N. Kolmogorov, *Limit distributions for sums of Independent Random Variables*, Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, (1968). Th.21.1, pp 99-- and M. Loève, *Probability Theory* I(4thEd), Springer-Verlag(1977). 22 pp303 Comparison Lemma.). May be, it answwer your problem partly.

Let $X=\{X_{nk},1\le k \le k_n, n\ge 1 \}$ be a triangular array of independent random variables in row(the $\{X_{nk}, 1\le j\le k_n\}$ are independent for each $n$), if $X$  satisfy
\begin{gather*}
    \lim_{n\to \infty}\mathsf{P}(\max_{1\le k\le k_n} |X_{nk}-\mathsf{E}[X_{nk}]|>\epsilon )=0, \quad \forall \epsilon>0.\tag{1}\\
    \sup_{n\ge 1}\sum_{k=1}^{k_n} \mathsf{Var}[X_{nk}] \le C.       \tag{2}
\end{gather*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}  \bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{k_n}[\log \bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u) - (\bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u)-1)] \bigg|=0 ,  \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    \bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u)=\mathsf{E}[\exp\{iu(X_{nk}-m_{nk})\}], \quad m_{nk}= \mathsf{E}[X_{nk}].
\end{equation*}
The proof of (3) is based on following inequalities,
\begin{gather*}
    \lim_{n\to \infty}\max_{1\le k\le k_n}|\bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u)-1|=0, \quad \forall u\in\mathbb{R}, \quad \text{by (1)}. \tag{4}\\
    \bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{k_n}[\log \bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u) - (\bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u)-1)] \bigg|\le \sum_{k=1}^{k_n}(\bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u)-1)^2, \tag{5}\\
    |\bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u)-1|\le \mathsf{Var}[X_{nk}]/2 ,\\
    \sum_{k=1}^{k_n}|\bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u)-1|\le C, \quad \forall n\ge 1, \quad \text{by (2)}, \\
    \sum_{k=1}^{k_n}(\bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u)-1)^2 \le 
    C\max_{1\le k\le k_n}|\bar{\varphi}_{nk}(u)-1|, \tag{6}
\end{gather*}
Using (5)and (4),(6), (3) is true.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and for your reply. I redid my question and I think it makes more sense now.